# Gradle version supportive for Logback v1.2.10

Tags: maven, gradle, grails, log4j, logback

Before the log4j shell issue happened last month I was using 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.5.22.RELEASE' which has internal dependencies on
ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.11  and ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.11 jars respectively.

After that log4j shell issue occurred I had upgraded both the jars to version ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3  and ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3 with gradle v3.5 which works fine. Now when I am trying to upgrade jars to logback-classic:1.2.10 and logback-core:1.2.10, this stops me while running the application stating below error:

`org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip'.`

Do I need to move to higher version of Grails or Gradle 3.5 have any issue with upgrade. Please any hint or guidance is most welcome.

Comment: Spring boot uses logback instead of log4j ...You should upgrade to a more recent version of Gradle...(currently 7.X ???) ... Furthermore you should upgrade to a more recent version of spring boot because spring boot 1.X is EoL current versions are 2.6.X ?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://logback.qos.ch/news.html

> We note that the vulnerability mentioned in CVE-2021-42550 requires
> write access to logback's configuration file as a prerequisite. Please
> understand that log4Shell and CVE-2021-42550 are of different severity
> levels. In response to CVE-2021-42550 (aka LOGBACK-1591) we have
> decided to make the following steps. 1) Hardened logback's JNDI lookup
> mechanism to only honor requests in the java: namespace. All other
> types of requests are ignored. Many thanks to Michael Osipov for
> suggesting this change and providing the relvant PR. 2) SMTPAppender
> was hardened. 3) Temporarily removed DB support for security reasons.
> 4) **Removed Groovy configuration support**. As logging is so
> pervasive and configuration with Groovy is probably too powerful, this
> feature is unlikely to be reinstated for security reasons. We note
> that the aforementioned vulnerability requires write access to
> logback's configuration file as a prerequisite. Please understand that
> log4Shell/CVE-2021-44228 and CVE-2021-42550 are of different severity
> levels. A successul RCE attack with CVE-2021-42550 requires all of the
> following conditions to be met: write access to logback.xml use of
> versions < 1.2.9 reloading of poisoned configuration data, which
> implies application restart or scan="true" set prior to attack As an
> additional extra precaution, in addition to upgrading to logback
> version 1.2.9, we also recommend users to set their logback
> configuration files as read-only

For now no support for grails so v1.2.9 onwards logback is not supported for now.

Comment: I'm going to be working on bringing back Groovy config for logback in a separate module, and securing the DSL, starting this weekend.